decode the pipe
     _                    _        _   _                  _            
  __| | ___  ___ ___   __| | ___  | |_| |__   ___   _ __ (_)_ __   ___ 
 / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ / _` |/ _ \ | __| '_ \ / _ \ | '_ \| | '_ \ / _ \
| (_| |  __/ (_| (_) | (_| |  __/ | |_| | | |  __/ | |_) | | |_) |  __/
 \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \__,_|\___|  \__|_| |_|\___| | .__/|_| .__/ \___|
                                                   |_|     |_|         


                |_|                 
|___\|_,__\__\  | |   /_\ |___\  |_|
 __( | |_( || | | |  / V \/__  | | |
|__ /| `_ /__ | | | / / \ \ _ /__' |
 ___  _ __ _| | | | __   _____ __ _ 
             _   _                  


I upvoted once I saw the great answer of @MOehm :)

The decoded text is:


                    _   _
   _ __ _____   __ | | | |_ __ _  ___
  | '__/ _ \ \ / / | | | __/ _` |/ __|
  | | |  __/\ V /  | | | || (_| | (__
  |_|  \___| \_/   | |  \__\__,_|\___|
                   |_|


To decode ...

 ... flip the ASCII art character-wise horizontally and vertically. This should just give a rotated image, but since the characters themselves are not changed, the encoded text becomes hard to read. But it's not entirely illegible, for example the rotated "rev" is easy to make out.

 (The double flip means that the slashes lean the same way as in the original. It's mainly the underscores that disrupt the image.)

What does it mean?

 The answer is composed of two Unix commands: rev reverses a line so that it reads backwards. tac displays several lines in the reversed order. (tac is cat backwards. cat means "concatenate", but used on a single item, it just "echoes" the input to the terminal.) The pipe symbol | means that the output of the first program is used as the input to the next. The initial input is the ASCII art in the question.

 I laughed when I saw the answer, because I had just used these two commands from my text editor to arrive at the solution. (But I did so in two separate steps, without piping.)


This sure is the correct answer. Amazing. Just for completeness: N fcrpvsvp pbzznaq jnf hfrq gb trarengr gur nfpvv neg. You also happen to know which one?

It looks like this here. (But I didn't know about it and it isn't installed on my machine.)

Yeah: here is the pipe able to encode and decode its own representation: "svtyrg 'eri | gnp' | eri | gnp".

FWIW: It seems somewhat newer "gbvyrg -s fgnaqneq" intentionally works identical as replacement. See: http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet. Nevertheless, both commands look rather unmaintained old, ... probably, and, hopefully fairly bug free :-)

Aha, interesting. When I have to create a banner, I usually create something myself with hash marks, X's or O's. It usually goes like this: Create new project directory; open readme file; spend half an hour to think of a good name; spend half an hour to draw a pretty ASCII logo; abandon the project. You'll notice that my projects never have bugs. :)
